# Setting ViewModel properties to private

Tags: swift

I have the following `ClassViewModel` where `customFilter` and `isLoading` are public, I wonder how to make them private in MVVM design pattern to make VMs not to be mutable.

As of now, these two properties are being accessed by `ClassViewController` class.

**ClassViewModel.swift**

```
final class ClassViewModel {
  var customFilter = CustomFilter()
  var isLoading = false
  let logManager: LogManager

  init(logManager:LogManager = .shared) {
    self.logManager = logManager
  }

   func adjustFilterOffset(by value: Int) {
       customFilter.offset +=  value
   }
}
```

**ClassViewController.swift**

```
class ClassViewController: UIViewController {
  private let classVM = ClassViewModel()

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  guard !classVM.isLoading else { return }

  if indexPath.row == classVM.customFilter.offset + classVM.customFilter.limit {
    classVM.adjustFilterOffset(by:20)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you’re  trying to achieve? You want to use them outside the class definition but you also want them to be private? Did you want read only in public maybe?

Comment: @WarrenBurton, I am trying to keep VMs properties to be private, but as you see I need to set or get the VM values in the VC. For example, I increment `customFilter.offset` by 20.

Comment: "to make VMs not to be mutable" But your view model _is_ mutable. It has two `var` properties. Privacy isn't going to change anything about that. Unclear what the goal is here.

Comment: @matt Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to encapsulate these public properties. I want to `get` and `set` these properties via ViewController. Trying to achieve more like a object oriented approach.

Comment: Well, as I say in my answer, the VC should know nothing about the VM's properties. You should give the VM some _methods_ that the VC _does_ know about.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're unhappy about is this line:

```
classVM.customFilter.offset +=  20
```

If that disturbs you, then it's up to you to provide, in your ClassViewModel, some sort of accessor *method* that allows the VC to tell the VM to adjust the offset. For example you might declare

```
func adjustFilterOffset(by: Int) {
```

You would make that method public, but keep your VM's properties private.

The typical architecture, indeed, is that the VM publishes a protocol providing a list of *intents*, i.e. things that someone else can ask it to do, in the form of methods it can call. The VC then refers to the VM thru that protocol and speaks to it only in terms of those methods.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I have added your approach to my question and updated accordingly. How about set or get the following properties `isLoading` ? or getting `classVM.customFilter.offset + classVM.customFilter.limit`